# Command Tilde not working

Tags: macbook-pro, macos

I'm using MacBook pro 15 with Yosemite 10.10.3. 
I can't get CMD + Tilde to work. In keyboard shortcuts it appears to be on.

What's the problem here?

Comment: Need more info, pictures... What/where/when... BTW, Cmd/~ can't be done using 2 keys, as it's a shifted character

Comment: @Tetsujin, in all apps (finder, xcode, safarai, chrome) I can't switch between opened windows.

Comment: Lol, I just plugged in external keyboard and it works; apperantely I used different keyboard layout so the tilde was placed differently on the keyboard.

Comment: Switch between open Windows is Cmd ` not Cmd ~ anyway, glad you figured it out

Comment: @Tetsujin It's also Cmd + ⇧ + ` (or Cmd + ~). It just goes in reverse order. Just like Cmd + Tab to switch apps, and Cmd + Shift + Tab to switch reverse order. Shift + some shortcut works with a lot of command. Like Undo: Cmd + Z; Redo: Cmd + Shift + Z...

Answer (score 2):

The tilde key was placed in a different place in the keyboard than the place I'm used to. Works like charm.